# Switching to use a background image from no background image via a multi-part post to the Twitter API with Ruby and OAuth

Tags: ruby, twitter, twitter-oauth, multipartform-data

I would like to change my profile background from no background image to a background image that I upload via the Twitter API using Ruby. I have no problems uploading new background images when my profile is already set to use an image as the background. When my profile is set to not use an image as the background, however, and I try to upload an image with the added param "use=1" to tell Twitter I want to use the background image I'm uploading, Twitter replies with this:

```
{"error":"You tried to turn on your background, but don't have one selected.",
    "request":"\/1\/account\/update_profile_background_image.json"}
```

suggesting Twitter's not recognizing that I'm uploading an image. In every other case, however, image uploading works perfectly. Adding the "tile" param with the request works too, so the problem doesn't seem to be with mixing file params and non-file params. I can even try to turn my background image off from being on while uploading a new image and Twitter gives me this:

```
{"error":"You tried to turn off your background while also uploading a new one.",
    "request":"\/1\/account\/update_profile_background_image.json"}
```

showing that Twitter is totally able to detect that I'm uploading an image.

Am I missing something?

Here's the code:

```
require 'oauth'
require 'net/http/post/multipart'

consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(APP_CONSUMER_KEY, APP_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    {:site => "http://api.twitter.com", :scheme => :header})
access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(consumer,
    {:oauth_token => OAUTH_TOKEN, :oauth_token_secret => OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET})

image_file = File.new(image_file_path)
url = URI.parse('http://api.twitter.com/1/account/update_profile_background_image.json')

req = Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart.new url.path, {
  "use" => "1",
  "image" => UploadIO.new(image_file, image_mime_type, image_file_name)
}

consumer.sign!(req, access_token)

Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port).start do |http|
  puts http.request(req)
end
```